# Differential equation of $x^2y = 4 + cy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> What is the differential equation of $x^2y = 4 + cy$?

The answer is $2x + xy' = 0$.

I try taking $y$ out:

$$y = \frac{4}{x^2 - c}$$

Then deriving:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{4}{x^2-c}\right] = -\frac{8 x}{(x^2-c)^2}$$

Am I doing something wrong? Is it possible the problem set is wrong?

Comment: I have some difficulties making sense out of this. Apparently you are given a family of curves, and your task is to find a common differential equation that has this family as its set of solutions. Is that correct? At least some of the answerers think that you only want to implicitly differentiate the given function (and that the value of the constant $c$ is known). Please clarify. The answer $2x+xy'=0$ doesn't really make sense either, because outside $x=0$ the solutions are $y=-2x+C$, and those don't really fit.

Comment: Problem set is wrong; I used implicit differentiation then substituted C from the original. Got 2y' + xy^2 = 0

Comment: A systematic method (which *always* work) is to isolate $c$ and then differentiate. Here,  $$c=x^2-4/y$$ hence $$0=2x+4y'/y^2$$ Rearranging, this yields $$y'=-xy^2/2$$ As I said, the method always win and one can apply it even when one's brain is switched off.

Answer (score 1):

You got y' right. Just subsitute the value of c from your main equation and plug it here.

Comment: i am getting -0.5xy^2

Answer (score 1):

From @Did 's comment

$$x^2y=4+cy \implies x^2=\dfrac{4}{y}+c$$

Differentiate wrt $x$ on both the sides.

$$2x=-\dfrac{4}{y^2}\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\implies \dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\dfrac{-xy^2}{2}$$

---

Continuing from your attempt. You can substitute back in the $y^2$ term you isolated into the expression for derivative and you get the required ODE

$$y=\dfrac{4}{x^2-c}\implies y^2=\dfrac{16}{(x^2-c)^2}$$
$$\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\dfrac{-8x}{(x^2-c)^2}=\dfrac{-x}{2}\cdot\dfrac{16}{(x^2-c)^2}=\dfrac{-xy^2}{2}$$